# laravel10 upgrade vite revert to laravel-mix problem

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, vite

I'm upgrading a fairly well advanced project from laravel 9 to laravel 10. Had a few issues but mostly these are resolved.

When I now do tests in the browser it is saying `Vite manifest not found` I've removed vite from npm removed the vite js file and reinstalled laravel-mix via npm. When i run `npm run dev` it compiles successfully using mix but when I reload the page it says vite manifest not found.

I followed the following tutorials:
https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix (near bottom of page)
https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix

Any ideas? How is my browser thinking I'm using vite? The correct assets are created via mix but this is not used.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

BlackLotus's comment above actually made me realise what the real issue was here. This was a view cache issue. It was resolved by running artisan on the command line:
`php artisan view:clear`
You can run `php artisan about` to see if you have anything cached or not.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to check your main layout `app.blade.php` under the resources/views folder the line @vite must be changed

Comment: Hi @BlackLotus, sadly this file has no reference to vite. Aglobal search using my ide for the word vite finds only references to invite. Made me think though that perhaps I was caching something though and it turned out that i was caching views. clearing this fixed my issue

Comment: @ThurstonLevi okay, maybe you should remember clear cache next time =)